# apply function to each element of a list nested r

Tags: r

I have a function like this:

```
a <- list()
a$prod_1 <- c(1,2,3)
a$prod_2 <- c(4,5,6)
```

and I want to exponentiante each element of the list
I tried something like this:

```
exp_a <- lapply(a, funtion(x) e^x)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? `lapply(a, exp)` will return a list of exponentiated vectors.

Comment: If I want to apply a function like 10^x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(a, exp)
```

Answer (score 1):

`e` doesn't exist as a constant in R, but the `exp`onential function does.
Just use `exp_a <- lapply(a, exp)`

Comment: I would like to use a customized function like 10 ^x

Comment: What is the problem then? lapply(a, function(x)10^x) will do that. Or do you need a different return format?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of ways to make it, while below are just two examples:

```
exp_a <- Map(exp,a)
```

or

```
exp_a <- as.list(as.data.frame(exp(do.call(cbind,a))))
```